# Send erc20 token with pay another address

Tags: web3js, tokens, ethereumjs, smart-contract-wallets

How can I do send USDT from `Address A` to `Address B` and pay fee from `Address C` with ETH.

I don't want to send gas from `Address A` and `Address A` only has USDT.

Does anyone have a sample code?

Comment: Currently it is not possible. The closest thing in Ethereum is if the token supports meta transactions.

Answer (score 0):

As you know all coin transfer functions regard as transaction and all transactions need gas fee